# Xamarin form toolbar items disappear when clicking back

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a page in my xamarin.forms app where i add two toolbar items in the XAML

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Refine" Icon="rfineitem.png" Activated="OnRefineClicked"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Sort" Icon="sorting.png"  Activated="OnSortingClicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

At first the items show but when i go to any page using Navigtion.PushAsync and then press the back button to return to the page the two items disappear

Comment: What platform are you experiencing this on? Are you using the latest version of Forms? I tested with a quick sample and I could not reproduce this so please also include an MVCE.